# How do I get a javascript library to work inside the CKEditor module?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

My content administrators want to be able to toggle back and forth between bootstrap nav-pills inside of the CKEditor instance. Out of the box, CKEditor doesn't seem to allow javascript to function in the editor. An example is below - I need to be able to click on the different pills to edit the associated content:

[image]

I have found an [associated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048401/how-do-i-allow-the-tabs-of-a-bootstrap-tab-to-work-within-the-ckeditor-editor) that seem to answer this issue but I cannot get it to work in Drupal - I don't know how to implement the code. I would add a comment to that question but I do not have sufficient reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code supplied in [this associated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048401/how-do-i-allow-the-tabs-of-a-bootstrap-tab-to-work-within-the-ckeditor-editor), I was able to get the javascript nav-pills to work in the CKEditor instance for Drupal 7. Unfortunately, it will only function in Firefox for PC. In addition, I had to add the following code to the ckeditor.config.js file as well as manually add the script to the admin theme's html.tpl.php file - this seems redundant but it will only work if both files have it.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
var jqScript = document.createElement('script');
var bsScript = document.createElement('script');

jqScript.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js';
bsScript.src = 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js';

var editorHead = ev.editor.document.$.head;
editorHead.appendChild(jqScript);
editorHead.appendChild(bsScript);

jqScript.onload = function() { editorHead.appendChild(bsScript); }; 
});
```